# CSS code not displaying things

Tags: html, css

I really don't know what I'm doing but I created the below code for a new page layout using Dreamweaver C6, div's and css.  It seems to work but I'm curious as to why in design mode my content area does not show the white background but in live mode or testing in browsers it does show the content background color.

I'm just trying to understand what's going on.  Please feel free to give any advice on how I have this written.  Keep in mind I really don't know what I'm doing.  It has taken me all week just to get to where I'm at.  I really struggled getting the header nav to align right and the menubar nav to be centered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0      Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>



<style>

*{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}   

html { 
min-height: 100%; 
margin-bottom: 1px; 
}


#container{
width: 800px;
height: auto;
margin: 0px auto;
border-right: 1px solid black;  
border-left: 1px solid black;
}

body{
background: #a6b17a;    
margin: 0px auto;
}



#header{
width: 800px;
height: 123px;
background-color: #c2c08d; 
margin: 0px auto;
}

#hnav{
width: 425px;
height: 15px;
background-color: ; 
margin-left: 375px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
text-align: right;  
}

#hnavbar ul { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0px; 
list-style-type: none; 
text-align: right; 
background-color: #000; 
height: 15px;
width: 400px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;

}
#hnavbar ul li {  
display: inline; 

} 

#hnavbar ul li a { 
text-decoration: none; 
padding: .2em .3em; 
color: #fff; 
background-color: ; 
text-align: right;

} 

#hnavbar ul li a:hover { 
color: #000; 
background-color: #CC3; 
} 


#hgraphic{
width: 425px;
height: 105px;
background-image: ;     
margin-left: 375px;
}



#menubar{
width: 800px;
height: 35px;
background-color: #000;
margin: 0px auto;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;    
text-align: center;

}

#navbar ul { 
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 0px; 
list-style-type: none; 
text-align: center; 
background-color: ; 
height: 35px;
width: 800px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;

}
#navbar ul li {  
display: inline; 

} 

#navbar ul li a { 
text-decoration: none; 
padding: 10px 8px; 
color: #fff; 
background-color: ; 
text-align: left;

} 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
color: #000; 
background-color: #CC3;  
} 



#content{
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
background: #fff;
margin: 0px auto;
}



#footer{
width: 800px;
height: 75px;
background: #000;
margin: 0px auto;
}

</style>



</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">

<div id="hnav">

<div id="hnavbar"> 
  <ul> 
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Locations</a></li> 
<li><a href="navtest1.html">Home</a></li> 
 </ul>
</div> 


<div id="hgraphic"></div>

</div></div>

<div id="menubar">
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul> 
<li><a href="#">Online Banking</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Onine Services</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Loans</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Deposits</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Trusts Invenstments</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Community News</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Community Club</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Identity Theft</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
</div>




<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a general guess, but Dreamweaver has it's own browser for previews - it might have it's own quirks in rendering things than a real browser. And sometimes (frequently) different browsers will render things differently too. I'd generally worry more about how it looks in Chrome/FF/Safari & their mobile versions than it does inside Dreamweaver for any site.

Comment: I subscibe to the creative cloud and it shows up fine in live mode http://i.imgur.com/QLTCtRJ.png

Comment: It is a little strange, everything looked fine in display and live mode and then I did something which caused the white content background to disappear in design mode.  I'll keep moving forward.  Thanks!!

Comment: so, is it working now?